# selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Пытаюсь запустить селениум вместе с драйвером
но выдает ошибку

```
C:\Users\Администратор>java -jar C:\\selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox/wires.exe"
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Unknown option: -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox/wires.exe
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parseValues(JCommander.java:742)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:282)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:265)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.<init>(JCommander.java:210)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3$1.setConfiguration(GridLauncherV3.java:228)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.buildLauncher(GridLauncherV3.java:138)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.main(GridLauncherV3.java:70)`
```

Делаю все по описанию с этого сайта https://bar-data.com/blog/other/install-and-run-selenium-for-windows
Помогите разобраться или хотябы расскажите как работать с селениум код не работает

Comment: В пути все слэши обратные, а последний - прямой. Попробуйте `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\wires.exe"`

Answer (score 0):

Я делаю по другому:

1. Загружаем exe файл драйвера  https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
2. Данный файл перемещаем в директорию установки python, директорию можно узнать введя в консоле windows:

---

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```

3. Запускаем:

---

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.get('https://github.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

как видите, вы неправильно скопировали пример. Обратите вниамние на символ `/`

знак `\`означает экранирование. то есть после этого знака в вашем случае пытается найти спецсимволы  `P` и `М`. По этой причине путь - невалидный.

правильнее будет

```
selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/wires.exe"
```

либо

```
selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\wires.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Исправить на: C:\Users\Администратор>java -jar C:\selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\wires.exe"